# Mongock Standalone not executing changelogs

Tags: java, mongock

I have the following configuration in my project but for some reason the change-log is never executed.
Any ideas on what I'm missing?

I can successfully use the mongo client and perform CRUD actions, it's just the MongockStandalone that's not working.

pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.cloudyrock.mongock</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongock-standalone</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.14</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.cloudyrock.mongock</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-v3-driver</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.14</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Driver code in main class:

```java
MongockStandalone.builder()
                 .setDriver(MongoCore3Driver.withDefaultLock(mongoClient, "demo"))
                 .addChangeLogsScanPackage("co.my.test.persistence.changelog")
                 .buildRunner();
```

Changelog class:

```java
package co.my.test.persistence.changelog;

//imports

@ChangeLog(order = "001")
public class Changelog001 {

    @ChangeSet(order = "001", id = "test", author = "Igor Flakiewicz")
    public void test() {
        // this method is never executed, the sout doesn't occur and breakpoints are not reached
        System.out.println("PLEASE WORK!");
        // migration code
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you're following the [quick start in Mongock's documentation](https://www.mongock.io/quick-start). Thanks to this ticket we have identified a bug in our documentation.
After building the runner with the following code:

```
MongockStandalone.builder()
             .setDriver(MongoCore3Driver.withDefaultLock(mongoClient, "demo"))
             .addChangeLogsScanPackage("co.my.test.persistence.changelog")
             .buildRunner();
```

You need to execute the method `execute()`

So the correct code you should be using is something like:

```
MongockStandalone.builder()
             .setDriver(MongoCore3Driver.withDefaultLock(mongoClient, "demo"))
             .addChangeLogsScanPackage("co.my.test.persistence.changelog")
             .buildRunner()
             .execute();
```